# PHP Extract and print latitude and longitude using geolocation with google geolocation api

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

```
<?php echo $lat; ?>, 
<?php echo $lng; ?>)
```

I'm trying to use the code from this page to get coordinates and dprint on the page above or below the maps using google,
http://www.galengrover.com/projects/PHPGoogleMaps-Examples/geolocation.php

I don't seem to understand how this works.

```
require( '_system/autoload.php' );
$map_options = array(
'map_id'        => 'map23',
'draggable'     => true,
'center'        => 'San Diego, CA',
'height'        => '500px',
'width'         => '500px',
'zoom'          => 16,
'bicycle_layer' => true
);
$map = new \PHPGoogleMaps\Map( $map_options );

// 
$marker = \PHPGoogleMaps\Overlay\Marker::createFromUserLocation( array( 'geolocation_high_accuracy' => true, 'geolocation_timeout' => 10000 ) );

$map->addObject( $marker );

// If you want to set geolocation options you must call enableGeolocation() explicitly
// Otherwise it will be called for you when you use geolocation functions
$map->enableGeolocation( 5000, true );




// Set the loading content. This will display while the browser geolocates the user.
$map->setLoadingContent('<div style="background:#eee;height:300px;padding: 200px 0 0 0;text-align:center;"><img src="_images/loading.gif" style="display:block; margin: auto;"><p>Locating you...</p></div>'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
  <head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>Ground Overlays - 
  <?php echo PAGE_TITLE ?>
</title>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">       
<?php $map->printHeaderJS() ?>  
<?php $map->printMapJS() ?>
</head>
  <body><h1>Geolocation</h1>( 
    <?php require( '_system/nav.php' ) ?> 
<p>This example finds your location and centers the map on it. It also uses map::setLoadingContent() to display a loading message to the user.
</p>
<?php $map->printMap() ?>(
<?php echo $lat; ?>, 
<?php echo $lng; ?>)
```

Comment: why not just use pure javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I edited the code to show you this. See geosuccess() function. It will alert your coordinates. Everything is stored in "this" so if you go to the console in google chrome and type in "this" you will see all the data there.

```
<?php

// This is for my examples
require( '_system/config.php' );

// Autoload stuff
require( '_system/autoload.php' );

$map = new \PHPGoogleMaps\Map;

// 
$marker = \PHPGoogleMaps\Overlay\Marker::createFromUserLocation( array( 'geolocation_high_accuracy' => true, 'geolocation_timeout' => 10000 ) );

$map->addObject( $marker );

// If you want to set geolocation options you must call enableGeolocation() explicitly
// Otherwise it will be called for you when you use geolocation functions
$map->enableGeolocation( 5000, true );
$map->centerOnUser( \PHPGoogleMaps\Service\Geocoder::geocode('New York, NY') );
$map->setWidth('500px');
$map->setHeight('500px');
$map->setZoom(16);

// Set the callbacks
$map->setGeolocationFailCallback( 'geofail' );
$map->setGeolocationSuccessCallback( 'geosuccess' );

// Set the loading content. This will display while the browser geolocates the user.
$map->setLoadingContent('<div style="background:#eee;height:300px;padding: 200px 0 0 0;text-align:center;"><img src="_images/loading.gif" style="display:block; margin: auto;"><p>Locating you...</p></div>');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geolocation - <?php echo PAGE_TITLE ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
    <?php $map->printHeaderJS() ?>
    <?php $map->printMapJS() ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function geofail() {
        alert( 'geolocation failed' );
    }
    function geosuccess() {
        alert("Lat:" + this.geolocation.hb + " Long: " + this.geolocation.ib);
        //alert( 'geolocation succeeded' );
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Geolocation</h1>
<?php require( '_system/nav.php' ) ?>

<p>This example finds your location and centers the map on it. It also uses map::setLoadingContent() to display a loading message to the user.</p>

<?php $map->printMap() ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, what I'm looking for is the code in PHP, or it would help if one can show me how to use (position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude) in PHP.

Comment: ok I just installed that plugin you are using and it worked :) so what is the issue?

Comment: use the that plugin to display the value of the coordinates on the same page below the map.

Comment: yep but where are you stuck? What have you tried? Is the plugin running? I can only help you if you elaborate more on the issue.

Comment: the script can detect my location and displays it on the map..  I'm using 
    <?php echo $lat; ?>, 
    <?php echo $lng; ?>) to find latitude and longitude values, I only get this (,)

Comment: Check out the edits. I would highly reccomend that you just use HTML5 to do this because php is really just generating JS for you anyways. Also the plugin is not very well documented whereas there are tons of info on HTML5 geolocation.